# Is there a systematic way to convert R code with loops to vectorized code?

Tags: r, loops

Most looping code looks like this

```
retVal=NULL
for i {
  for j {
    result <- *some function of vector[i] and vector[j]* 
    retVal = rbind(retVal,result)
  }
}
```

Since this is so common, is there a systematic way of translating this idiom?

Can this be extended to most loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [plyr](http://had.co.nz/plyr) package provides a set of general tools for replacing looping constructs when you're work with a big data structure by breaking it into pieces, processing each piece independently and then joining the results back together.

Answer (score 2):

The first goal should to get *working* code. You are there.  Then try some simple optmizations.   E.g.

```
retVal <- matrix(NA, ni, nj)     # assuming your result is scalar
for (i in 1:ni)
   for (j in 1:nj)
       retVal[i][j] <- *some function of yours*
```

will already run *much* faster as you do not reallocate memory for each i,j combination.

As for the looping, you can start by replacing the inner loop with something from the `apply` family.  I am not aware of something fully general to answer your question -- it depends what arguments your function takes and what type of return object it produces.

Comment: Gotcha. One generalizable thing I get from your response is that preallocating a matrix is a good idea when you have two subscripts running over a vector. Another idea might be crossing the original vector by itself to make a matrix and then use matrix operations to get a result matrix.

Comment: Yes, there _may_ better ways with direct matrix (i.e. two-dim) indexing.  Just how can, say, exponeniate all elements of a matrix.
But the pre-allocation effect is already huge -- I have an example with timing in my 'intro to high-performance computing with R' tutorials.